# What does this phrase mean? “You could have heard a pin drop.”

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does this phrase  mean?

> You could have heard a pin drop.

Comment: It was so quiet you could have heard a sound which is normally undetectable.

Comment: and what about undetectable?

Comment: What does "undetectable" mean? It means you can't see/hear/feel etc.

Comment: yes.What does "undetectable" mean?

Comment: Have you searched it up, user3552625? It's easily googleable (the whole phrase).

Comment: You might be more comfortable on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I recall an actual instance of this when I was in the 4th or 5th grade.  The teacher told us to lay our heads down on our desks, be really quiet, and take an nap for 15 minutes or so.  When the time period was over she dropped a sewing pin on the floor, and several of us heard it hit the floor.  We must have been amazingly quiet.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/you-could-have-heard-a-pin-drop

Answer (score 1):

This is a figure of speech (rhetoric) and it consists in an exageration. Nobody can hear a pin drop and even more so in a normal environment, where there are people talking, the noise of the street in the background, etc. Therefore, before having the least opportunity for hearing a pin drop, perfect silence is needed. This hyperbole (as this sort of rhetorical figure is also called) emphasize then how complete was the silence in the place where a pin could have been heard if it had dropped.